# Activate Datapipeline passing parameters value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline, aws-sdk-nodejs

The full picture: there's a ETL process in Datapipeline and we need the users to update some items on demand, but we can't update all database because it's to expensive.

The initial proposed solution is to trigger an AWS DataPipeline via API. Is it possible to activate the Pipeline with some parameter?

The API and the Pipeline already exists, so it would be the less effort solution. Either way, if you've some suggestion about this case, I'd appreciate.

Thanks in regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameter values to the pipeline when activating it. For example, from the Ruby SDK documentation for the [activate_pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/DataPipeline/Client.html#activate_pipeline-instance_method) method:

```
resp = client.activate_pipeline({
  pipeline_id: "id", # required
  parameter_values: [
    {
      id: "fieldNameString", # required
      string_value: "fieldStringValue", # required
    },
  ],
  start_timestamp: Time.now,
})
```

Values sent this way will override the ones defined when you created the pipeline.

So if your pipeline has a parameter called `my_last_update_time` you could supply a value for it in the `parameter_values` argument, and that way it can be different each time you run the pipeline. The CLI and Java SDK have the same mechanism.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had a bad understanding about this method but it's exactly what i needed. A little detail that i learned by experience: if at least one paramater_value is setted, its necessary to supply all values, otherwise they would be set as null.

Comment: If a parameter is not defined during pipeline creation, can it be added during activation?